# Use JavaScript to Get SelectedValue ASP.NET RadiobuttonList

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have the following radio button list on an .aspx page:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbList" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Text="I accept" Value="accept" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="I decline" Value="decline" Selected="True" />
</asp:asp:RadioButtonList>
```

The second radio is selected by default. Is there a way for me to determine if a user hasn't selected the first option, i.e., "decline" is still selected when they perform an action?

E.g.:

```
function checkRbList() {
  var rbl = document.getElementById(<%= rbList.ClientID %>);

  //if "decline" is still selected, alert('You chose to decline')...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this HTML rendered:

```
<label>
  I accept
  <input id="rbList_0" name="rbList" type="radio" value="accept" />
</label>
<label>
  I decline
  <input id="rbList_1" name="rbList" checked="true" type="radio" value="decline" />
</label>
```

You can use [**`document.getElementsByName()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName). Then by using:

`document.getElementsByName("rbList")` you'll get a [**`NodeList`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

This is the function:

```
function checkRbList() {
  var rbl = document.getElementsByName("rbList"), len = rbl.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (rbl[i].checked) { // If checked?
      return rbl[i].value; // Returns the selected value.
    }
  }
}
```

To check if `"decline"` is still selected:

```
var targetValue = "decline";
if (checkRbList() === targetValue) {
  alert("You chose to decline.");
}
```

Something like this:

```js
(function() {

  var targetValue = "decline";

  function checkRbList() {
    var rbl = document.getElementsByName("rbList"),
      len = rbl.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (rbl[i].checked) { // If checked?
        return rbl[i].value; // Returns the selected value.
      }
    }
  }

  var btnValidate = document.getElementById("btnValidate");
  btnValidate.onclick = function() {
    console.log(checkRbList()); // Prints the selected value.
    if (checkRbList() === targetValue) {
      alert("You chose to decline.");
    }
  };

})();
```

```html
<label>
  I accept
  <input id="rbList_0" name="rbList" type="radio" value="accept" />
</label>
<label>
  I decline
  <input id="rbList_1" name="rbList" checked="true" type="radio" value="decline" />
</label>

<button id="btnValidate" type="button">Validate</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do the job:

```
var rbl = document.getElementById("<%= rbList.ClientID %>");    
var value = rbl.value;
if(value === 'decline')
    alert()
```

Comment: Missing apostrophes around the ClientID

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that is working:

```
var targetValue = "decline";
$('#<% = myBtn.ClientID %>').click(function () {
    var items = $("#<% = rbList.ClientID %> input:radio");
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if (items[i].value == targetValue) {
            if (items[i].checked) {
                alert(items[i].value);
            }
        }
    }
});
```